Discrete periodic Schrodinger operator as a direct integral
I have seen several articles referring to the fact that periodic Schrödinger operators are direct integrals, for example section 2 in this paper or section 1.2 in this paper. Most eventually refer to the book "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Volume 4" by Simon and Reed.
In chapter 16, they define a direct integral Hilbert space and  operators which are direct integrals. Theorem 85 seems to be the general framework for studying the spectrum of such operators, but I believe that Theorem 99 is the actual tool needed to work with these objects in my setting.
I am interested in an operator $H$ acting on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ by
$$ H = - \Delta +V $$
where $V$ is a multiplication operator coming from a real function $v:\mathbb{Z}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $1\leq j \leq d$ there exists $p_j\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $v(m_1,...,m_j+p_j, ...,m_d)= v(m_1,...,m_j, ...,m_d)$ for all $(m_1,...,m_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d$.  I have been told that one can equivalently consider a family of matrices with parameters $\theta\in \big( \mathbb{R}/ 2\pi \mathbb{Z} \big)^d$, which I denote by $H_{\theta}$, such that $\text{spec}(H)= \cup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi)^d} \text{spec}\big( H_{\theta} \big)$.
If we denote $Q= \Pi_{j=1}^d \{ 0,..., p_j -1 \}$, then $H_\theta$ acts is an operator on $\ell^2(Q)$. We have for  $m_1,m_2\in Q$
$$ \langle H_{\theta} \delta_{m_1}, \delta_{m_2} \rangle = \begin{cases} 1 &, \Vert m_1-m_2\Vert_1 =1\\ V(m_1) &,m_1=m_2 \\ e^{-i\theta_j} &, \text{if } (m_1-m_2)_j=1 \\  e^{i\theta_j} & ,  \text{if } (m_1-m_2)_j=-1 \\ 0 &, \text{else}. \end{cases} $$
However, I am having a bit of problem seeing how this is two view points coincide.
It seems that $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ has a direct integral like structue, where we can write $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)= \int_{[0,2\pi)^d}^\oplus \ell^2_\theta(\mathbb{Z}^d)d\theta$ and $\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ are functions satisfying $\psi(m_1,...,m_j+p_j,...,m_d)= e^{2\pi i \theta_j} \psi(m_1,...,m_d)$ for all $j$ and $(m_1,...,m_d)\in \mathbb{Z}^d$.
I would appreciate any hints or explanations, as I am not able to really understand the direct integral like structure of these operators. I would hopefully like to see how

For physicists, this is just Bloch's theorem. The idea is that your potential is $\Lambda = \prod_{i=1}^d p_i\mathbb Z$-periodic. You can therefore decompose your Hilbert space in eigenspaces of quasi-momentum.
Mathematically, consider the $d$ translation unitary operators $T_1,...,T_d$:
$$
T_i\delta_m = \delta_{m-\delta_ip_i}
$$
which all commute:
$$
[T_i,T_j] = 0
$$
You can therefore decompose your Hilbert space $E$ into a direct integral of simultaneous eigenspaces:
$$
E = \int^\oplus_{\theta\in\Theta}E_\theta d\theta
$$
with $\Theta = \prod_{i=1}^d \mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$, so that for $\psi\in E_\theta$:
$$
T_i\psi = e^{i\theta_i}\psi
$$
i.e. $e^{i\theta}$ are the eigenvalues of the translation operators (physically, $\theta$ is the quasi-momentum rescaled to the size of the fundamental domain). Therefore, each $E_\theta$ is finite dimensional, of dimension $D = \prod_{i=1}^dp_i$. Indeed, you can view each vector to be of the form:
$$
\psi_m = e^{i\theta\cdot m}\phi_m
$$
with $\phi$ $\Lambda$-periodic, which automatically gives you the dimensionality of the space (this is Bloch's theorem).
Since $H$ commutes with the $T_i$, it stabilises the eigenspaces $E_\theta$. It therefore acts on it as a finite dimensional operator. You can quantify it as a matrix in an appropriate basis. To get your matrix, just look at its action on the $\phi$. I think that you made a mistake though, for the third and fourth cases. The condition should rather be:
$$
(m_1-m_2)_j=p_j-1 \quad (m_1-m_2)_j=-p_j-1
$$
i.e. this gives the modified quasi-periodic boundary conditions, giving you a transition between the opposing faces of your parallelepiped domain.

Thanks for your answer. You're right about my mistake. I think I wanted to write mod $p_j$ but somehow didn't write it. I know that this is Bloch theorem, but I was trying to understand it using the direct integral formulation. Can you elaborate a bit more on why and how we decompose the original Hilbert space to the direct integral form?

Mathematicians call this the Floquet-Bloch decomposition, and the Reed-Simon theorem 99 you reference is tackling the continuum analog of what you need in your setting. The two perspectives are similar, however.
Consider $\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)\subset \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)$ as you defined it: denote by $mp=(mp_1,\dots,mp_d)$
$$
\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)=\{\psi\in \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d):\psi(n+mp)=e^{2\pi i(mp\cdot \theta)}\psi(n) \}
$$
The consideration of this space is motivated as in the other answer: it's easy to check $H$ fixes these spaces. We note for now that $\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d) $ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb C^{p_1\dots p_d}$, or your $\ell^2(Q)$ in a canonical way, namely sending $\mathbb{V}:\delta(e_jn_j)\to e_{jn_j} $ for $1\leq j\leq d$ and $1\leq n_j\leq p_j$. Formally, this is where your $H_\theta$ acts.
Let's see how the direct integral decomposition you mention works:
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^d}^\oplus \ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)d\theta=\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)
$$
works by introducing the Floquet-Bloch transform.
Formally, the direct integral is the Hilbert space defined as the $L^2$ space of $\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)$ valued functions on the torus:
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^d}^\oplus \ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)d\theta=\{ f:\mathbb T^d\to \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d): f\;\text{measurable and}\;\int_{\mathbb T^d}\|f(\theta)\|_{\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)}<\infty
$$
with inner product
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb T^d}\langle f(\theta,g(\theta)\rangle_{\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)}d\theta
$$
(the earlier portion of the same chapter of Reed-Simon is useful for this construction).
The Floquet-Bloch transform will then give a unitary map between $\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)$ and the above direct integral of Hilbert spaces. It is usually initially defined on $\psi\in \ell^1(\mathbb Z^d)$ as
$$
\mathbb U: \ell^1(\mathbb Z^d)\subset \ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)\to \int_{\mathbb T^d}^\oplus \ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)d\theta\\
(\mathbb U\psi)(\theta,n)=\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z^d}\psi(n+pm)e^{-2\pi i(\theta\cdot m)}
$$
and then extended to an isometry by density. $\mathbb U$ then conjugates $H$ to a direct integral of finite dimensional operators. Indeed, note that we can write an orthonormal basis for $\ell^2(\mathbb Z^d)$ as $\{ \delta(n+mp):m\in \mathbb Z^d, n\in \Lambda\}$ where
$$
\Lambda=\mathbb Z^d\cap \prod_{j=1}^d[0,p_j)
$$
is a fundamental cell. Formally, composing $\mathbb U$ with the canonical isomorphism $\mathbb V$ (this really being pedantic) described above, we have (after correcting the mistake the other answer pointed out)
$$
\mathbb U\left(\int_{\mathbb T^d}\mathbb VH_\theta\mathbb V^* d\theta\right) \mathbb U^*\delta(n+mp)=H\delta(n+mp)
$$
where $\int_{\mathbb T^d}  VH_\theta\mathbb V^*d\theta$ is the direct integral of operators $VH_\theta\mathbb V^*$ that act on the fibers $\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)$ as you expect from your expression. This is enough to check equality of the operators.
There are details to fill in to be sure, but I hope this helps.

Thank you very much, this is the sort of answer I was looking for. I'll need to fully digest the details in your answer.

No problem, let me know if I can clarify further

Can you explain how $V$ acts? I am unclear about how you defined it. Also, is it true to say that $(\mathcal{U}\psi)(\theta,\cdot)$ is a function in $\ell^2_\theta(\mathbb Z^d)$?
